# Which frame work should i use for development of PHP-MYSQL Human Resource Management System

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, zend-framework, symfony-2.1

I'm allotted to develop Human Resource management system of our university. Which include salary, leave, gpf, pensions as per govt regulations. I have 3 months of time to develop the Web based software. I want to know is there any customized open source hrms solutions which i can use or in which framework i need to use for the development of said software for better result and functionality. 
Please give me your Kind suggestion.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

### Choices

CakePHP, CodeIgniter and Yii are some of the easier to learn frameworks and they may be good choices for the beginning of such a project.

Zend and Symfony2 are usually the enterprise choices, they offer a bigger feature set and have bigger communities but they do come with a steeper learning curve.

Symfony2 in my opinion is the most complex choice available and it is bringing a lot of much needed standardization in the PHP community. It has a lot of features and it is very elegantly designed, intuitively so, allowing it to be easily extended with non-Symfony pieces of code who happen to follow the PSR standards.

### Duration

Doing all of what you said in 3 months on a framework you're unfamiliar with is a pretty big goal even for a very experienced developer.

In my opinion unless you have a team at hand to help you with this and help you with testing you won't be able to finish it or perhaps you will but at the very least quality-control and feature-completeness will suffer.

Your university should be paying professionals to either do this job or to buy a ready made product for this task otherwise the legal implications may not be pleasant if any miscalculations occur anytime.

If you find an Open Source application you could use that would be a better choice for this task since it already does all of what you planned it to do and more the only issue is adapting it to do things precisely the way you want it to which depending on the code quality and complexity can be a breeze or can be harder than writing the application from scratch.

### My choice

I'd (now) choose Symfony2 for any project I'd work on of any size even though CakePHP might be easier to install/setup and get running.

Since this application is one of the ERP suite type of applications there is a high likelihood that your University will be stuck with this application for a number of years and any new applications would need to either be built on the same framework or would have to communicate intensely with this application. Because of this I'd choose Symfony2 all over again.

Developing in Symphony2 is a very good experience and it should help new developers learn standards, common practices and good practices. Yet another reason I'd choose Symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

you probably got downvoted because this is not the right place to ask this question / your question is too much generic, please keep in mind this for your next questions.

I can just give you my two cents about a great framework: [**Codeigniter**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter). I think it is one of the best to start with, easy to use, good documentation. It could not be the best ones to fit your needs, but for what I have understood from your question (not very complete indeed), it should be fine.